# Set visual studio online check-in policies online

Tags: visual-studio, azure-devops

When creating a new project in Visual Studio Online, I can set all it's required settings online, but then I have to connect to it through Visual Studio and configure the check-in policy there before handing it over to the team to use.

I don't work on every project, I create it and then hand it over to the team who will take it further so I don't want to have to connect to each project that gets created.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is not a direct way to enable TFS check-in policy except connecting to the team project and setting in the team explorer.

Or you'll need to use the Team Foundation Server SDK to implement the function that set check-in policy programmatically, here is a blog "How to Set Check-in Policies for all Projects in Team Foundation Server using PowerShell?", you may have a look: http://manasbhardwaj.net/set-checkin-policies-projects-team-foundation-server-using-powershell/